# Multiple transpose in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame like this:

```
country a
country b
country c
country d
123
567
789
101
asd
dfa
dgf
fgh
```

I want convert to this:

```
country a      123      asd
country b      567      dfa
country c      789      dgf
country d      101      fgh
```

Data.frame contains a lot of row, so I can't subset according rownames. `t` function convert like this:

```
country a countryb countryc countryd 123 567 789 101 asd dfa gf fgh
```

So, `t` is not useful that I want.

Comment: Are there always two strings `country` `a` for first set, and numbers for second set and one string `asd` for the third set?

Comment: `data.frame(split(df, rep(1:3, each = 4)))`

Comment: Would that not work only if there are four rows each of that kind?

Comment: or `unstack(data.frame(df, var = rep(1:3, each = 4)), V1 ~ var)`

Comment: @Gopala Yeah, that's the assumption I made. If there's missing data, it gets a lot more complicated really fast.

Answer (score 1):

One way of splitting this data frame is using matrix.
I'll assume that you know the final number of columns (ncols).

```
# data frame example
df = data.frame(x = c("country a","country b","country c","country d",
                         "123","567","789","101","asd","dfa","dgf","fgh"),stringsAsFactors = F)

# ncols: Known number of columns
ncols = 3  

df = data.frame(matrix(df$x, dim(df)[1]/ncols, ncols), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Result:

```
> df
         X1  X2  X3
1 country a 123 asd
2 country b 567 dfa
3 country c 789 dgf
4 country d 101 fgh
```

If you use this approach, keep in mind that the number of rows of the original data frame should be a multiple of the number of columns. If not, you will get a warning and the missing data will be filled using the original df from the beginning

Answer (score -1):

One solution is this, assuming the pattern show above is the way it is...(someone may have better regex matching than I have. :)

```
as.data.frame(cbind(df$V1[grep('country \\S+', df$V1)],
                    as.integer(df$V1[grep('\\d+', df$V1)]),
                    df$V1[-grep('country \\S+|\\d+', df$V1)]))
```

Output as follows:

```
         V1  V2  V3
1 country a 123 asd
2 country b 567 dfa
3 country c 789 dgf
4 country d 101 fgh
```